# how can use jedis cluster keys method?

Tags: java, jedis

ok ,i use jedis cluster keys method :

```
@Autowired
private JedisCluster cluster;
Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, JedisPool> entry : 
cluster.getClusterNodes().entrySet()) {
   Jedis jedis = entry.getValue().getResource();
   Set<String> _keys =  jedis.keys(pattern);
    keys.addAll(_keys);
}
```

but ,this code throw exception,:

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR unknown command 'KEYS'
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:127)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:161)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:276)
at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.keys(Jedis.java:246)
```

pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
  <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't know if I write wrong! please help me, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

keys command is not supported by jedis cluster yet, and I'm not sure if it will ever be supported in the future.

You may use scan instead.

Comment: hao can use scan method